# Silverstripe and 301 RedirectMatch

Tags: silverstripe

I have built a site that needs to have legacy urls redirected. The legacy site used a data objects as page concept, so blog entries were found at example.com/news/view/my-post. The new site uses the blog module, so blog entries are now found at example.com/news/my-post. I tried adding the following redirect to my htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/news/view/(.+) http://www.example.com/news/$1
```

When I navigate to an old post, for example, example.com/news/view/my-post with the above RedirectMatch in place, I get the following url: mysite.com/news/my-post?url=/news/view/my-post and get a 404 from Silverstripe

Another strange behavior is that when I append anything but ?url=* (for example ?everything=everything, I don't get the 404 page).

Is Silverstripe appending the ?url=/news/view/my-post to the url? How can I add a RedirectMatch and not receive a 404 from Silverstripe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe apache's mod_alias (which provides the RedirectMatch directive) is conflicting with mod_rewrite. Use mod_rewrite instead -- and take care to insert your rules BEFORE the default one's SilverStripe typically places in its .htaccess file.

The rule will look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news/view/(.*)$ /news/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

... SilverStripe Rules come after this.
```

`RewriteEngine On` ensures that these rewrite rules will be processed. It's OK to have this in you virtualhost/.htaccess multiple times -- but keep in mind that only rules appearing AFTER the first occurence will be processed. I typically place it in my virtualhost definition.

`[R=301]` indicates a permanent 301 redirect. Use [R=302] if it's temporary.

`[NC]` is used to ignore case, making the regular expression match case insensitive.

`[L]` will immediately return this rule, and stop the processing of subsequent rules.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html for reference